# What's the best way to save set of objects locally in react-native?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

AsyncStorage is unable to retain data and I have run out of options to save 
a set of objects and update them with new entries to the list. Please help

Answer (score 5):

For Handling App's Data:
[State](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) - It handles component's internal data with not much complexity.
[Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html) - It tosses data back and forth from parent component to children and vice verse.
[Redux](http://redux.js.org/) - It handles data efficiently using action-reducer-store architecture. Great for a complex app with a lot of user's data to handle.

For Data Persistance:
[AsyncStorage](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.46/docs/asyncstorage.html#asyncstorage) - Simple API to save and manage data on device manually.
[Redux Persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) - Built over Redux to store all the Redux State data to device synchronously.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Realm could be your solution: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/index.html

> Realm is a mobile database that runs directly inside phones, tablets or wearables. This project hosts the JavaScript versions of Realm.
>
> Currently we only support React Native (both iOS & Android) and Node.js (on MacOS and Linux) but we are considering adding support for Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic as well.
>
> Features
>
> - Mobile-first: Realm is the first database built from the ground up to run directly inside phones, tablets and wearables.
> - Simple: Data is directly exposed as objects and queryable by code, removing the need for ORM's riddled with performance & maintenance issues.
> - Modern: Realm supports relationships, generics, and vectorization.
>   Fast: Realm is faster than even raw SQLite on common operations, while maintaining an extremely rich feature set.